# What is the definition of 'regular local' and 'regular' for noncommutative rings?

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I have been trying to find out what the definition of a *noncommutative regular local ring* is, but to no avail. In fact, how does one even begin to define Krull dimension for a noncommutative ring? Hence, I would appreciate it if someone could kindly provide definitions for the following, in the case when the ring under study is noncommutative:

- **Regular**. In the commutative case, the definition of *regular* involves localizing at prime ideals. However, in the noncommutative case, how do we do localization? Is Ore's Condition invoked somewhere?
- **Regular local**. In the commutative case, the definition of *regular local* involves Krull dimension. However, in the noncommutative case, do we have an analogue of Krull dimension?

On a different note, in the commutative case, is it true that a local ring that is regular the same as a regular local ring? (This might seem to be a stupid question.)

Comment: why not just use the projective dimension definition?

Comment: Unfortunately, noncommutative algebraists are not so lucky as to have every commutative concept find a noncommutative analogue with all the same features :) Nevertheless, I like the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noncommutative localization is a highly nontrivial concept! There have been practical extensions of localization to noncommutative rings, but the thing to know is that it is not nearly as nice as commutative localization.

For a good survey of noncommutative localization, you can check out all of chapter 9 in T.Y. Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings*.

Another very advanced book on localization ideas is Bo Stenström's *Rings of Quotients*. I know that Lambek also has a book *Noncommutative Localization*, but I have not had the chance to read it.

The motivation for studying regular local rings is their geometric connection with *regular points*. Since I know so little about noncommutative geometry, I can't make any comment on whether or not it is a meaningful question to ask in the noncommutative case, but hopefully someone reading can comment on that.

---

As for the final question: Suppose $R$ is a local ring that is regular, with maximal ideal $M$. Then $M$ is prime, and by the definition of regular rings $R_M=R$ is a regular local ring.

Comment: @MannyReyes Is there a type of regular local ring that makes sense for noncommutative geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a ring with centre $Z$. H. Bass (Algebraic $K$-Theory, p. 122) and C. W. Curtis & I. Reiner (Methods of Representation Theory Vol. 2, p. 22) give the definition:

> $R$ is **right regular** if every finitely generated right $R$-module has a finite resolution by finitely generated projective right $R$-modules.

Bass then gives the following results:

> - If $R$ is right regular, then $R$ is right noetherian.
> - If $R$ is right regular, then $Z'\otimes_Z R$ is right regular for every localisation $Z'$ of $Z$.
> - Assume that $R$ is finitely generated as a module over $Z$. Then $R$ is right regular if and only if $Z_{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes_Z R$ is right regular for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $Z$.